# Apply Bayesian framework to estimate linear regression parameters

Tags: python, regression, bayesian, inference, pymc

I'm new to Bayesian framework, and I have started with [Kruschke's book](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/) and [BDA](https://avehtari.github.io/BDA_course_Aalto/gsu2023.html) course to understand some theory to solve my problem.
My problem is very common: I have some collected data x,y and I need to estimate the slope and intercept of the linear regression from x and y. Usually, I perform a frequentist analysis with [characteristic values](https://izw.baw.de/e-medien/geotechnical-safety-and-risk-2011/PDF/3%20Risk%20and%20Reliability%20in%20Geotechnical%20Engineering/3_29.pdf) with a confidance level of 95%. But I have tones of old sampled data that I would like to use as prior knowledge to my new sampled data, so I'm moving to the Bayesian framework.

What I know is that my x,y data follows a log-normal distribution.
From that, I need to create my model.
My steps were:
for testing and modeling, I have created synthetic data that are quite similar to my real data and split it into priori (80%) and new data (20%).

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


N = 265
A = 0.438
B = 12.13
x = np.random.uniform(44, 2900, N)
sigma = 167
y = A * x + B + np.random.normal(0, sigma, size=N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6,4))
ax.scatter(x,y, label='Data')
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()

# All data
data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

#  x and y are  vectors of collected data over the years
total_samples = data.shape[0]
prior_samples = int(0.8 * total_samples)  
print(' 80% as priori: {:.0f} observations'.format(prior_samples))

# Randomly shuffle the data (
indices = np.arange(total_samples)
np.random.shuffle(indices)

# Split data into prior knowledge and new data
x_prior = data.x[indices[:prior_samples]]
y_prior = data.y[indices[:prior_samples]]

x_new = data.x[indices[prior_samples:]]
y_new = data.y[indices[prior_samples:]]
```

Then, I have fitted a log-normal to my data:

```
prior_mu_x, prior_sigma_x = np.log(x_prior).mean(), np.log(x_prior).std()
print('prior x: μ = {:.2f}, σ = {:.2f}'.format(prior_mu_x, prior_sigma_x))

prior_mu_y, prior_sigma_y = np.log(y_prior).mean(), np.log(y_prior).std()
print('prior y: μ = {:.2f}, σ = {:.2f}'.format(prior_mu_y, prior_sigma_y))
```

and finally created a model:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    prior_dist_x = pm.Lognormal('prior_dist_x', mu=prior_mu_x, sigma=prior_sigma_x)
    prior_dist_y = pm.Lognormal('prior_dist_y', mu=prior_mu_y, sigma=prior_sigma_y)


    slope = pm.Normal('slope', mu=0, sigma=10)
    intercept = pm.Normal('intercept', mu=0, sigma=10)

    sigma = np.std(y_new, ddof=1)  
    likelihood = pm.Normal('likelihood', mu=slope * x_new + intercept, sigma=sigma, observed=y_new)

  
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000, cores=1)  

    # Plotting
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
# Create a scatter plot of the data points
ax.scatter(x,y, label='Data')

# Set labels and title
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel('y')


# Add a legend
plt.legend()
plt.show()
ax = pm.plot_trace(trace)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

my doubts are in the model part:

- Am I doing this right?
- What parameters should I use as the mean and standard deviation inside my pm.model for
  the slope and intercept?
- What standard deviation should I use for the likelihood in my pm.model? Here I have used the variability of the new data, but I'm not sure about that.